# How to properly close a Tkinter application using threads

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple app that shows a basic GUI and runs a simple web server in background. I currently have this code running just fine:

```
import Tkinter
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import threading
import time
import webbrowser
import json

# Load configuration
json_data=open('config.json')
configuration = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()


# -----------------------------------------
#           configuration
# -----------------------------------------
host = configuration["host"]
port = configuration["port"]
folder = configuration["folder"]
url = host + ":" + str(port) + "/" + folder


# -----------------------------------------
#           Web Server
# -----------------------------------------
class WebserverThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        self.PORT = port
        self.Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
        self.httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", self.PORT), self.Handler)

        print "--- serving at port", self.PORT
        self.httpd.serve_forever()

    def close(self):
        self.httpd.shutdown()
        print "Exiting web server Thread"

# create & start webserver thread, launch browser
thread1 = WebserverThread(1, "Thread-1")
thread1.start()
webbrowser.open_new( url )



# -----------------------------------------
#           Graphic User Interface
# -----------------------------------------
# Create window
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry('200x200')
top.resizable(width=0, height=0)

# start GUI
top.mainloop()

# Handle exit
print "Exiting Main Thread"
thread1.close()
```

If I close the GUI window using the window close button (red circle in OSX), the app takes a few seconds and exits properly. The problem comes when I try to close the app using Cmd+Q, in which case the app gets frozen and won't get closed (I need to force it to close since it won't respond).

I tried removing the web-server code (the thread) and the the problem doesn't happen anymore, so it looks like something keeps running there, but I have no idea how to handle it.

So, in essence, how can I handle and properly close the app when the user tries to close the app via Cmd+Q?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind the Cmd+Q event with Tk's "Bind" command

```
def callback(event):
    print("Cmd-Q recieved, shutting down thread");
    thread1.close()        # stop the webServer thread
    # call any additional exit handler you want
    root.destroy()         # destroy root window, my syntax may be wrong here

top.bind("<Cmd-Q>", callback)
```

You can decide how to send a message to your webServerThread.